# Generating prime numbers of the form $\lfloor \sqrt{3} \cdot n \rfloor $

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms

How to prove the following claims ?

Let $b_n=b_{n-1}+\operatorname{lcm}(\lfloor \sqrt{3} \cdot n \rfloor , b_{n-1})$ with $b_1=3$ and $n>1$ . Let $a_n=b_{n+1}/b_n-1$ .

1. Every term of this sequence $a_i$ is either prime or $1$ .
2. Every odd prime of the form $\left\lfloor \sqrt{3}\cdot n \right\rfloor$ greater than $3$ is a term of this sequence.
3. At the first appearance of each prime of the form $\left\lfloor \sqrt{3}\cdot n \right\rfloor$ greater than $5$, it is the next prime of the given form after the largest prime that has already appeared.

A few first terms of this sequence can be found at [A323388](https://oeis.org/A323388) .

Implementation of this generator in PARI/GP can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwlzDEOwyAMheGdU3S0G6rWzmj5MDgKEgolCSH3L6jLe9I_fEX5I85IZ3E5XU3HLHUNbQWUh4t7hU3ZF2-sRlNevhDz3ut11gYzPjf0RihBjd9GL5IhHHeD8T6gdNx4WEdN5Z9RfploJNM=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: What makes you think it is true that "every term is prime or $1$" ? If it is only the 72 first terms then to me it is obvious it is not true.

Comment: @reuns [Searching for a counterexample to the first claim .](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVy0EOgyAQQNG9p9DdTKVpB5eTOQzTQkJQsKA7Dy_9y5f8LPT-x4OSLDyEUiGJNdmoFaV5_WwQ1tK1_eoBCz4SGiVkJ2pfSk_iPqrlGGCC2Pbmz2_Za9w8OByva3QihKZLPrqwVu8SIt8qIyPB&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: @PeđaTerzić .I could not get the calculation. could you please calculate one in simple form.

Comment: @sirous What calculation you have problem with?

Comment: @PeđaTerzić, for example how the number 83 in the sequence is found?

Comment: @sirous By using recurrence given in the second line of this post.

Comment: @sirous [Try this one.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwlzDEKgDAMheG9p3BMtCKpDkLIYRpREGvVWu-vxeU9-IcvyjCyUZKeTVjvLGWmNPs8A3JlliPBJs5Gq06UmjDtsITjq_eVMvRYb2iVkL2o65Ra4iKcT4by1iN_uLpinWmNf0Z-AZ38JN0=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: @PeđaTerzić I can't understan 3 very well. $a_7=13 =\lfloor 8\sqrt(3)\rfloor$ but the largest prime so far is 5 which is not the previous prime. Can you clarify that please?

Comment: Is there any reason for choosing $b_1=3,m=3$?  I tried to observe more generally 
 $b_n=b_{n-1}+\operatorname{lcm}(\lfloor \sqrt{m} \cdot n \rfloor , b_{n-1}),b_1\in\{2,3\}$, then for $m$ that is not a square number, $a_n$ seems to be composite only finitely many times. And if $b_1=km,k\in\mathbb N$, then it also seems to be the case for square numbers $m$ as well.

Comment: @Vepir There is no special reason. Try $m=5$ with $b_1=182$ or $m=6$ with $b_1=26$.It seems that for every non-square positive integer $m$ there is a suitable starting value $b_1$ for which sequence $a_i$ is consisted of prime numbers and $1$'s only. Pozdrav iz Crne Gore!

Comment: @EstebanCrespi I hope that I clarified  the third claim now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We prove that the second and the third claims are true.

**The second claim is true.**

If $a=d\alpha$, $b=d\beta$ and $(a,b)=d$, we have $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b) / b = \alpha = a / d.$

We may rewrite the sequence $a_n$ using above.

$$
a_1=1,$$
$$
a_n=\frac{\lfloor(n+1)\sqrt 3\rfloor}{\left(\lfloor(n+1)\sqrt 3\rfloor, (a_{n-1}+1)\cdots (a_1+1) 3 \right)}, \ \ n\geq 2.
$$

Thus, if $n\geq 2$ and $\lfloor(n+1)\sqrt 3\rfloor=p>3$ is prime, then $p$ cannot divide $a_i+1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n-1$.

It is clear that $p$ cannot divide $a_i+1$ for $1\leq i\leq n-2$. Otherwise, $p | a_i+1 \leq \lfloor (n-1)\sqrt 3 \rfloor +1<\lfloor(n+1)\sqrt 3\rfloor=p$ is a contradiction.

To see that $p$ cannot divide $a_{n-1}+1$, assume otherwise. Then $p|a_{n-1}+1 \leq \lfloor n\sqrt 3\rfloor +1\leq \lfloor(n+1)\sqrt 3\rfloor=p$. This gives the equality 
$$
p=a_{n-1}+1=\lfloor n\sqrt 3\rfloor +1=\lfloor(n+1)\sqrt 3\rfloor.  
$$
Then $\lfloor n\sqrt 3 \rfloor = p-1$ is an even number. Moreover, $\lfloor \sqrt 3\rfloor = 1$, $\lfloor 2\sqrt 3\rfloor=5$ gives $n\geq 3$. But, $2=a_1+1$ gives
$$
a_{n-1}=\frac{\lfloor n\sqrt 3 \rfloor}{\left(\lfloor n\sqrt 3\rfloor, (a_{n-2}+1)\cdots (a_1+1) 3 \right)}\leq \frac{p-1}2 <p-1.
$$
This is also a contradiction.

Therefore, we have $a_n=p$ in such case.

**The third claim is true.**

Recall that
$$
a_1=1,$$
$$
a_n=\frac{\lfloor(n+1)\sqrt 3\rfloor}{\left(\lfloor(n+1)\sqrt 3\rfloor, (a_{n-1}+1)\cdots (a_1+1) 3 \right)}, \ \ n\geq 2.
$$

Suppose that $n\geq 2$ and $\lfloor(n+1)\sqrt 3\rfloor = p>3$ is prime. Then we have for any $1\leq i\leq n-1$, 
$$
a_i\leq \lfloor (i+1)\sqrt 3 \rfloor \leq \lfloor n\sqrt 3\rfloor < \lfloor (n+1)\sqrt 3 \rfloor =p, 
$$

Therefore, $p$ is the next prime of the given form after the largest prime that has already appeared.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the OPs 3rd conjecture. Are you sure he's not asking whether $p=\lfloor (n+1)\sqrt{3}\rfloor$ is the next prime in the sequence after the previously largest prime?

Comment: @WillFisher It may not do so. See the first occurrence of  $17=\lfloor 10\sqrt 3 \rfloor$ and it is the next prime after $5$. And the previously largest prime is $13$, it is before $5$. In fact, $13, 5, 17$ are consecutive prime values of the sequence.

Comment: Note also that OP has changed this posting, and not the OEIS. The third conjecture in the OEIS is therefore not true. An equivalent but easier statement of the third conjecture in this posting is, "at the first occurrence of primes of the form $\lfloor n\sqrt 3\rfloor$, it is larger than any of the previous primes in the sequence."